# tomcat giving java lang.NullPointerException in application

Tags: tomcat5.5

I am getting the following error when i run my application, The application was running fine but after restarting tomcat the following error started.Pls help .

Type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.aprisma.spectrum.app.repmgr.container.SRMWebApplicationContextUtils.getBean(SRMWebApplicationContextUtils.java:67)
    org.apache.jsp.repmgr.admin.recoverReportingDBLandscape_jsp._jspService(recoverReportingDBLandscape_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.27 logs.

Regards

Aswani Dev

Comment: we need to see your code / dir structure , as I doubt that your code is looking for some jar which is not present there